# Conservation of Angular Momentum of an Inviscid Fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, flow, vortex

I was trying to prove that the angular momentum of an ideal MHD plasma, defined by
$\vec{L} = \int \rho \vec{r} \times \vec{u} \ dV$ is conserved when there are no external torques. That is:
$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}=0$. Seems simple, but I'm having a really hard time figuring this out. Here's what I've done so far:
$$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \int \vec{r} \times \left (\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} \vec{u} + \rho \frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} \right)$$
$$=-\int \vec{r} \times \left ( \vec{u} \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u}) + \rho \vec{u}\cdot \nabla \vec{u} + \nabla p \right )$$
where I've just substituted the continuity and the momentum equations for an inviscid fluid. This is pretty much where I'm stuck. I've thought about using the fact that $\vec{r} = \nabla (r^2/2)$ and the following vector identity:
$$\nabla \psi \times \vec{A} = \nabla \times (\psi \vec{A}) - \psi \nabla \times \vec{A}$$
to simplify things. This helps get rid of the pressure gradient term, since I can use Gauss's theorem to get rid of it. However, I don't know what to do with the first two terms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!